# Symbolic logic application of Simplification rule

Tags: logic

I am studying symbolic logic and am stuck at this question:

> Is the following a correct application of the rule cited? If not, say why not and what would be needed in order for them to be correct applications.
> $$
> (A \bullet \sim B) \supset (C \bullet \sim D) \,/ \therefore A \supset (C \bullet \sim D)
> \tag{Simp.}
> $$

I understand why it is not correct application (major operator is not conjunction) but I can’t explain the part “what would be needed in order for it to be correct application”.

Comment: Can you show us what the rule cited (“Simp.”) looks like?

Comment: Use CP (Conditional Proof): assume $(A \land \lnot B)$ and then apply Simp to get: $(A \land \lnot B) \to A$ and $(A \land \lnot B) \to \lnot B$

Comment: The rules apply to the **main** connective; thus, in order to apply Simp we need a formula where $\land$ is the main connective, e.g. $\varphi \land \psi$.

Comment: @Jollywatt sorry the rule is Simp

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you so mucH!!

Comment: @RisingSenorita We understand the rule is _called_ "simp", but not all of us know what that is. Can you show its definition or tell is what book it’s from?

Comment: Edit: “Simp” refers to the [simplification rule of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination).